# Objective-C: Trouble reading cocos2d api doc

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to read the [cocos2d api doc](http://www.sapusmedia.com/cocos2d-iphone-api-doc/) but I'm confused about what the [...] means in something like:

```
- (float) scale [read,write,assign]
```

I am expecting a type and a parameter name, so something like

```
- (void) addFrameWithFilename: (NSString *) filename
```

makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a description of a property (and those are separated out as such in the docs you linked to). Those are [property attributes](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) in the []; in this case they are indicating the existence of two methods, a getter (read) and setter (write):

```
- (float)scale
- (void)setScale:(float)value
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are Objective-C 2.0 properties.  There is a [good tutorial](http://theocacao.com/document.page/510) on the topic.

Basically, if you have an instance `foo`, you can access and modify the property by doing something like:

```
foo.scale = 3.0f;
```